# Streaming private tracks from Soundcloud's API using a Custom Player

Tags: streaming, soundcloud

So I know there's plenty of SoundCloud documentation on creating custom players -- as well as streaming private sounds with their own player.

But I can't find a definitive answer to:

**Can I stream private tracks through my own custom player using the API -- but WITHOUT requiring any SoundCloud login authentication?**

--

Or in bullet form, I want to know if i can:

- stream Soundcloud hosted tracks
- these tracks must be private and NOT publicly available on SoundCloud
- the player must be completely of our own design
- no SoundCloud login is required for anyone to listen to these tracks

--

I realize this would just make SoundCloud into a music hosting service, so just wondering if anyone has done this.

Comment: So hey, i also wanted to post the same question, did you find out a solution of how to do it?

Comment: I wanted to let you know what I am doing, I am using the HTML5 audio tag and using the src attr of the audio tag to point the soundcloud uri. This works for almost all cases, but there are a few tracks which cannot be streamed like this, for example some tracks dont have the stream_url key in the response json. Seeing this I went to soundcloud.com and tried to debug using the chrome console. I played the same song on soundcloud.com(I was not authenticated) and it works, this is the link of that song obtained from soundcloud.com

Comment: https://api.soundcloud.com/i1/tracks/81489386/streams?client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28&app_version=3a7032f

Comment: One thing I noticed is that "i1" text is present in the URL which is not present in any of the other streaming calls I make(The ones that work). So this track which I have mentioned above is a private track?

Comment: Anything new on this???

Comment: I'm trying to get this sorted out. Here is a CodePen - if it is any help to others... http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/ZGJMda   decent setup to trouble shoot this

Answer (score 1):

in theory, yes, you can do that.

first you'll need to gain access token for the users who has uploaded these private tracks. (this should happen on server side)

after that, you will impersonate every visitor on the site as this default user, and he will have access to the tracks.

but, this is not a good practice. 
you need to be worried about is that you need to hide this token pretty good, so the visitors can't abuse it.

my suggestion is to create a server code that will do all the job related to access token (getting tracks, getting tracks streams etc), and in client side just show the final results. this way, you'll keep your access token safe.