# How play a private track with soundcloud Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I have a problem with my privates tracks. I have public track and privates tracks in my soundcloud account. When a track is public is correcte, but when i'm a private track the api return an 404 error :
GET http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/123?client_id=xxxxx&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200 404 (Not Found) in my console.

Here my function for to play a track :

```
// Play a Single track 
$('#app').on('click','.play_btn_single',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this);
    var id = el.attr('id');


    SC.stream('/tracks/'+id,function(sound){
        sound.play();
    });


});
```

Thank you of your help.

Comment: You cannot play it BECAUSE it is private.  Make it public and try again.

Comment: I tried and it's correcte. Do you possible to play a private track? I should send an access token to have access to my private track.

Comment: You cannot use it if it's private.

Comment: I should necessary put all my tracks in public. I think their are a solution for to play a private track.

Comment: You will put them public, or do you need a different solution?

Comment: I found in this website this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076885/soundcloud-api-how-to-play-private-sound-with-html5-audio-tag. I tried it, but I has a same error (404).

Comment: You have another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to play a private track. The easiest is to use private HTML5 widget (as [Jameal G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4171542/jameal-g) correctly noticed) – for that you just need to click "share" button on a track’s page, select "embed" tab and copy the iframe code to insert on your website.

Otherwise, if you want to play it with your own code, then you have to use `secret_token` that you can get when sharing the track on the website (when authorised) or when querying the API, also authorised (so providing the HTTP header `Authorization: Oauth 123…`).

Then the client application can use that secret token to query API and play your sound without authorising the users. Below is a simple example where I share my private track:

HTML:

```
<audio controls></audio>
```

JS, assuming jQuery, but the idea should be clear:

```
var clientId = 'client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    sekretToken = 'secret_token=s-wwC6c',
    trackUri = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/128310939.json?' + 
               secretToken + '&' + clientId,
    audio = jQuery('audio');

jQuery
  .get(trackUri)
  .then(function (result) {
    // do not forget to supply client_id also when querying for stream url
    audio.attr('src', result.stream_url + clientId);
  });
```

http://jsbin.com/yerilu/edit?html,js,output

**UPD**.
How to find the secret token.

1. On SoundCloud website, go to the page of the private track that you own, while authorised on the website, then press "share" button (second from the left under "write a comment" input). You will see a text input field titled "Private Share" – copy the link and the last part after the slash is the secret token.
2. You can also query the API when authorised (so you must send Oauth HTTP header, like `Authorization: Oauth 123…`, of course you will have a longer number for your own token) for your tracks and the track representation will have `secret_token` property with the value of the token you could use.

Comment: Do you that the secret token is accessToken (SC.accessToken)?

Comment: When I clicked private share. I seek a code s-XXXXX to end url.

Comment: But I don't understand the point 2 I have a 401 error (Unauthorized)

Comment: You don't have to use both, if first way works for you, it's cool.

Comment: I have another ideal. I can to use Soundcoud Player for my private tracks

Comment: yeah, @jameal-g has suggested that earlier.

Comment: Thank you very much @jameal-g and @gryzzly! One day my website will available in English and you listen to my music! I close this topic.

Comment: Please do not remove the question – it might be useful to other people!

Comment: No I don't remove the question. :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide an authentication token if you wish to play sounds from an account that are not public. From SoundCloud's API Guide:

> "Note that as long as the sound is public, you'll only need to provide
>   a client_id when creating a client. If you would like to access the
>   stream URL for a private sound, you'll need to authenticate your app."

For instructions on authentication, see: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication

Comment: okay... If a user has not Soundcloud account he cant listen my private on my website?

Comment: Correct.  Users would need a soundcloud account.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your question. It appears you can stream authenticated users' private tracks but not your own. In the [comments of this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956812/streaming-private-tracks-from-soundclouds-api-using-a-custom-player), user1386101 offers a solution for streaming your own tracks but it was not validated by the community.

Comment: Alternatively, you can [embed a secret widget](http://blog.soundcloud.com/2010/11/10/secret-link-widget/) and use the [widget API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget) to interact with it.

Comment: @pianoman99 not entirely correct, if you have secret_token value you can play private tracks to un-authorised clients